# assignment error while assigning different class objects

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I have overloaded the assignment operator inside the class `b` but
I am getting compilation error after executing below code snippet:

```
error:
cannot convert 'a*' to 'b*' in assignment
  bobj=aobj;
 ^
```

and due to this error it seems to be `bobj->showname();` is not also functional as still content of `aobj` is not copied to `bobj` and it is still behaving class `b`'s object. I never been able to perform assignment between different kind of objects. I believe it is possible to assign different class of objects.

Code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class a {
    int a1;
public:
    a(int _a1 = 0) : a1(_a1) {}
    void showname() {
        cout << "class name a with value =" << a1 << endl;
    }
};

class b {
    public:
        const b& operator=(const b& rhs);
    private:
        a* cobj;
};

const b& b::operator=(const b& rhs) {
    a* origobj = cobj;
    cobj = new a(*rhs.cobj);
    delete origobj;
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    a* aobj = new a;
    b* bobj = new b;
    bobj = aobj; //error during assignment 
    bobj->showname();
    return 0;
}      

//problem section updated with other scenario
  class Bitmap {};
  class widget
  {
  public:
  const widget& operator=(widget & rhs)
 {
 Bitmap *origobj=obj;// backup of original pb
 obj=new widget (*rhs.obj);//make pb point oto a copy of *pb
 delete origobj;//delete the original pb
 return *this
 }

private:
Bitmap *obj;
 };
```

Comment: You're trying to assign pointers, not objects, as the error message says. And using far too many pointers in general.

Comment: i can't use smart pointer and stl here due to limitiations of my device where this code is targeted .

Answer (score 2):

Please see below link for code snippet as a solution of your problem. I completely agree that you must use smart pointers but as you said that it is not permitted due to some limitation of your application they you don't have any choice :).

Link:  https://ideone.com/wq9kdO

Code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class a 
{
int a1;
public:
a( int _a1=0):a1(_a1)
{
}
void showname()
{
cout<<"class name a with value ="<<a1<<endl;    
}
};

class b
{
public:
b(a* cobj) : cobj(cobj)
{
cout<<"object initialization\n";    
}
void display()
{
 cobj->showname();  
}

private:
a *cobj;    
};

int main() {
a aobj(10);
b bobj(&aobj);  
bobj.display(); 
}
```

Explanation: If there is no relation between two classes but still one class is interested some of the functionality of other class then solution should be either private inheritance or composition. in your scenario I don't think so private inheritance seems to be feasible as you are not overridden public/protected virtual function so you need to go with composition only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer with good explanation. at least you deserve up votes :).  @ admin : I believe you must have provision for  upvotes/downvotes after  receiving answer. I don't think so the person who gives complete information while asking questionon  this forum deserve down votes. I never experience the same on other forums . Other forums questioner will have right to upvote/downvote after  getting answer from forum member.

Comment: don't i deserve  upvote for this answer. If  you really  liked this  please upvote me for this answer.

Comment: I don't see up voting option here. It seems to be down vote option is only applicable here  :)

Answer (score 1):

as you all know the answer which i had shared doesn't represent modern c++ standards. on the request of questioner i did the same old way. below is  my answer based on modern c++ standards , I am sharing the same as it will be good learning lesson for programmers who are new to modern c++ era.

link: https://ideone.com/efdU2l

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;
class a 
{
int a1;
public:
a( int _a1=0):a1(_a1)
{

}
void showname()
{
cout<<"class name a with value ="<<a1<<endl;  
}
};
class b
{
public:
b(std::unique_ptr<a>cobj) : cobj( std::move(cobj))
{
cout<<"object initialization\n";  
}
void display()
{
 cobj->showname();  
}
~b ()
{
cout<<"deleted the object of a"<<endl;

}
private:
std::unique_ptr<a> cobj;    
};

int main() {
std::unique_ptr<a> aobj (new a (10)) ;
b bobj(std::move(aobj));  
bobj.display(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement assignment operator properly. below is the code snippet for the same.

```
const b& b::operator=(const a& rhs) {

if(&rhs!=cobj)
  {
   delete cobj;
   cobj=new a(rhs);
   }
    return *this;
}
```

Now assign them `*bobj = *aobj;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `aobj` in a `b` because `b`'s assignment operator only understands arguments of type `b`.  If you add a constructor to `b` that can accept an argument of type `a`, then it will cast `aobj` to `b` using that constructor.  This will fix your problem.

Comment: I don't understand , why downvotes for the same?????. if you don't have proper  explanation please keep quite. Apart from this in my application  due to some limitation i can't use smart pointer and STL as  this code needs to be executed on snmp devices which takes very minimum memory.

Answer (score 0):

a has no relation to b. It is like doing

```
std::string* str_p = new std::string("Hello");
std::vector<double>* vec_p = new std::vector<double>();
str_p = vec_p;  // doesn't make sense.
```

Also, follow Mikes advice: Stay away from pointers.

Now on the other hand if std::vector contains a string, the vector allows you to manipulate that value; or if a *b* contains an *a*. You need to let *b* allow the user to set the *a*. This is not done by overloading the assignment operator. Maybe something like

```
a obj;
b b_object;
b_object.set_a(obj);
```

Comment: you mean to say ,if two class which doesn't have any relation and still one class want to perform assignment operator  using other class's object which is ptr to heap object then it is not possible?

Comment: @user2907032 possible, but not reasonable.  You can overload `operator=(other_type rhs)` but this is rarely a good idea unless it is a well-defined conversion like `str = "hello";`.

Comment: lets get into more details by realistic issue so that it will help both of us.

Comment: lets get into more details by realistic issue so that it will help both of us.if you see i am already overloading operator for this.lets get into more details by realistic issue so that it will help both of us.In below example Widget contains Bitmap and now widget need to manage the Bitmap by providing assignment and copyconstructor as well. currently we will focus only on assignment operator. So is there any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: class widget{
   public:
   const widget& operator=(widget & rhs)
    {
    Bitmap *origobj=obj;// backup of original pb
    obj=new widget (*rhs.obj);//make pb point oto a copy of *pb
    delete origobj;//delete the original pb
    return *this
   }
  
   private:
   Bitmap *obj;
   };

Comment: Other example would be smart pointer implementation. if you would have seen the smart pointer implementation the you would have observed that smart pointer class contains other class object (class parameter is declared as template) as a heap allocated and then smart pointer performs all the require operation like copy constructor , assignment operator  etc.

Comment: @user2907032 Create a new question. It is impossible to discuss this in a comment section.

Comment: I can't do that  unless and until current  issue is not address properly. There would be more chances of down votes as i already faced in current post.